# Random sem repetição

Tags: java, android

Bom tenho uma dúvida que ta me matando já tem tempo, e não consigo resolver. 
PS: Sou iniciante em Android.

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de sorteio, mas não estou conseguindo de forma alguma gerar um Random sem repetir os números já sorteados, já tentei de tudo, mas ainda assim ele repete o número.

Segue o Código:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    final NumberPicker InicialNP = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.inicialID);

        InicialNP.setMinValue(0);       
        InicialNP.setMaxValue(700);     
        InicialNP.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        InicialNP.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
 public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){

            }
        });

    final NumberPicker FinalID = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.finalID);

        FinalID.setMinValue(0);       
        FinalID.setMaxValue(700);       
        FinalID.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        FinalID.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
 public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){

           }
        });

        EditText Nomesorteio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomesorteioID);
        EditText Resultado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultadoID);
        Button Sortear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsortear);            
        Sortear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     


    private int mostrarresultado() {    

          inicial = InicialNP.getValue();
          finall = FinalID.getValue();
          Random Random = new Random();
          int Resultado = Random.nextInt(finall + 1 - inicial) + inicial;  

          return  Resultado;                      
        }


    private void verifyRepeated(int removeValue) {

          int getParams = removeValue;
          Random random = new Random();
          getParams = random.nextInt(finall + 1 - inicial) + inicial;   

            while(true)
                    {
                if(!repeat_list.contains(getParams))
                    break;
                else                        
                    getParams = random.nextInt(finall + 1 - inicial) + inicial;
            }

            repeat_list.add(getParams);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "O valor sorteado foi: " + Integer.toString(removeValue), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {     
            list.clear();
            click = MediaPlayer.create (MainActivity.this, R.raw.click); 
            click.start ();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorteando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
            int Resultado = mostrarresultado();

            verifyRepeated(Resultado);

        } 

    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça dessa forma:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> repeat_list = new ArrayList();

private int inicial;
private int finall;

private int mostrarresultado() {                    
    inicial = editTextInicial.getValue();
    finall = editTextFinal.getValue();
    Random Random = new Random();
    int Resultado = Random.nextInt(finall + 1 - inicial) + inicial;  

    return  Resultado;                      
}


private void verifyRepeated(int removeValue)
{
    int getParams = removeValue;
    while(true)
    {
        if(!repeat_list.contains(getParams))
            break;
        else
            getParams = Random.nextInt(finall + 1 - inicial) + inicial;
    }

    repeat_list.add(getParams);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "O valor sorteado foi: " + removeValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {     
    list.clear();
    click = MediaPlayer.create (MainActivity.this, R.raw.click); 
    click.start ();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorteando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               
    int Resultado = mostrarresultado();

    verifyRepeated(Resultado);

}
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que estava procurando, muito obrigado!
mas, só conseguir colocar assim:  private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

E continua repetindo os números, mas agora eu já tenho uma ótima base para tentar resolver, muito obrigado!

Comment: Deu certo ? @J.Silva

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido de limapr a lista toda vez que a função é chamada hehe

Comment: Não sei se o problema está aqui -> private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(); por que eu não conseguir usar static, mas ainda está repetindo

Comment: Então tipo.. nesse seu caso você teria que separar o local onde você fará o random e o local onde irá adicionar as entradas

Comment: Você só tem que ter em mente, que o valor que você sorteou tem de ser removido da lista toda  vez após ser randomizado

Comment: Ainda não conseguir =/ tem algo errado no meu onClick?
Só consigo usando: private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(); 
Mas ainda repete os números.



 @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {  
    click = MediaPlayer.create (MainActivity.this, R.raw.click); 
    click.start ();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorteando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    int Resultado = mostrarresultado();
       resultado1.setText(Integer.toString(Resultado));   
   
   }   
   
  });
  }

Comment: Edita seu código la em cima, com o seu botão onClick

Comment: Editei da uma olhadinha

Comment: Ok 1 minuto....

Comment: Desculpa todo esse trabalho, é minha primeira aplicação Android, olha como fica: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/foto2-png--28

Comment: Reeditei de uma olhada

Comment: Sucesso, era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Comment: De alguma forma ainda está repetindo, tem alguma coisa errada na minha Atividade?
PS: Editei o código

Comment: Edite sua pergunta lá em cima, e poste seu código

Comment: Não estou conseguindo postar o código :(

Comment: Posta lá em cima, reformulando a "SUA" pergunta...

Comment: Pronto. Da uma olhadinha Por favor.

Comment: Cara vou pedir que você de uma estudada antes em orientação a objetos e clean code, seu código está muito bagunçado...

Comment: Vou fazer uma limpeza nele exatamente hoje, estou a dias tentando resolver esse problema da repetição para poder Limpar todo o código.

Comment: Tranquilo fico no aguardo =)

Comment: Dei uma melhorada no código. Ficou melhor?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66964/discussion-between-j-silva-and-matheus).

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67053/discussion-on-answer-by-matheus-random-sem-repeticao)

Answer (score 6):

Tente armazenar seus valores em um **`Set<Integer>`**. O tipo de dado **Set** é uma lista que não armazena valores repetidos. Com isso você irá garantir que os valores armazenados não se repitam.

PS: `Integer` é uma classe wrapper do tipo primitivo `int`.

Comment: Essa é a melhor resposta. Em um trabalho da faculdade, eu precisava gerar uma quantidade muito grande de números aleatórios. Fazendo com lista, as consultas de duplicidade levavam muito tempo por serem o(n). Depois que troquei por um Set, que é sempre o(1), o programa decolou. Ficou muito rápido mesmo, gerava milhares de números em segundos.

Comment: Você pode me da um exemplo de como eu faço isso?

Comment: @J.Silva você precisa criar uma coleção de dados do tipo `Set<int>` que é uma `Collection` assim como `List<>`, e nesta coleção você adiciona os retornos das chamadas ao seu método `mostrarresultado()`. Isso garante que os retornos não se repitam, sem falar que a implementação e até mesmo a complexididade do seu algoritmo ficará bem mais simples.

Exemplo:

`Set<int> resultados = new HashSet<int>();`
`resultados.add(mostrarresultado());`

Comment: `Set<Integer>` e não `Set<int>` - tipos primitivos não podem ser usados como genéricos no Java.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é. Não prestei atenção a este detalhe.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve usar o comando **Collections.shuffle()**, dessa forma sempre será um número aleatório e não irá repetir, exemplo:

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = inicial; i <= finall; ++i){
    number.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(number);
```